# The first API call after login is unauthorized until page reload (Laravel Sanctum & VueJS)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I am trying to resolve this 401 issue for some time. After logging in and obtaining the token I am setting it as a header, but keep getting 401 exception on first load of the page. The error goes away after refresh. It seems that the token is not written to store or localStorage the first time around. Here's my code for login (I set the token to state.token in the mutation):

```
retrieveToken(context, credentials) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios.post('api/login', {
        email: credentials.email,
        password: credentials.password,

      })
        .then(response => {
          const token = response.data.access_token
          localStorage.setItem('access_token', token)
          context.commit('RETRIEVE_TOKEN', token)
          resolve(response)
          console.log(response.data)
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
          reject(error)
        })
    })
  },
```

And that's how I set it to header (setting it from localStorage doesn't solve the issue):

```
const authorizedApiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_PRODUCTION_URL,
  
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${store.getters.token}`
  }   
})
```

This behavior baffles me. Is there any theory or suggestions on how to debug?

Comment: It seems like the request is being authenticated with the session cookie and not the Bearer token. I would look into how Sanctum prioritizes cookies over tokens if its the same domain.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. When I remove the token I get back to non-authorized status, though. And I don't do anything about the cookies at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess when the axios client is created the token is not yet retrieved from api. Try setting the header before each request using an interceptor:

```
const authorizedApiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_PRODUCTION_URL,
  
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json'
  }   
})

authorizedApiClient.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  if (store.getters.token){ // or get it from localStorage
    config.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + store.getters.token
  }
  return config
})
```

Comment: Thank you. That seems to be working. I was thinking about interceptors, but used them incorrectly!